# Trouble piping output of command into zathura

Tags: bash, pipe, zathura

The zathura man page states

> zathura displays the given files. If a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name, the content will be read from standard input. If no files are given, an empty zathura instance launches.

Indeed, this works in bash if I run the command `cat document.pdf | zathura -`. However, I am unable to generalize this to other cases. Specifically, if I create a folder containing only `document.pdf`, running the command `ls | zathura -` returns an error, saying that zathura could not determine the file type. Why is this? Am I misunderstanding how piping works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat document.pdf | zathura -
```

Pipes **the content** of `document.pdf` to Zathura, which tries to render it.

```
ls | zathura -
```

**If** you have only `document.pdf` directory and nothing else, that pipes the string `document.pdf` to Zathura, not its contents, so Zathura complains. Moreover, if you try to write a program and it involves [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you are most probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. Is there any way to get around this? I agree that generally parsing `ls` is not ideal. However, the specific task I was trying to accomplish was to open the most recent file in a directory with zathura. All the files are generated by myself and I have no intent of ever adding anything weird, like newlines, into the file name. Accessing this file (or I guess more precisely, the string) can be done with `ls -Art | tail -n 1`, but piping this into zathura gives the same error for the reason you described.

Comment: @HenryShackleton You're welcome. In that special case, I think you issue `cat "$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)"|zathura -`. Although I never used Zathura, I guess that would be equivalent to `zathura "$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)"`. However, in case you want to do something robust, something with `find -exec` would be good.